# Misconfigured: App Sorry, That Helps hasn't been approved for display in App Center

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a simple Facebook App that I use to allow users of my website to login with Facebook. Recently I added a basic custom story via the open graph API, e.g.

> Nick plays a mixtape via anexample.com

The custom story appears in my stream as expected, however when I click the anexample.com link on the story I get the following error and cannot access the actual Facebook App page:

> Sorry, the details for anexample.com cannot be displayed because the app is
>   misconfigured.

What is strange, is that the application redirects at

https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=AN_APPLICATION_ID

despite the fact that the app is not registered as a game.

Has anyone else faced this behaviour?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you configured a App on Facebook integration?

Comment: @WizKid Yep! We've created Facebook App ID and use the [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) rails gem to handle the authentication. We've been using this app for authentication for some time now without any issues.. and now that we're trying to create a custom story our app has been converted to a 'game'.
Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: We are getting a similar issue on our app.. did you find a solution/reason for the above behavior yet?

Answer (score 0):

On tapping on the App link, you could navigate it in one of the two possible ways

- Any FB page: Add the page in Advanced settings of your App.
- A website: Add a web platform